# Working on a simple door lock

Tags: arduino-uno

this is my first project on an Arduino platform. My aim is to build up a door lock unlockable by playing a short melody on a one-octave piano keyboard. I think the idea is cool!
I'm thinking at everything, but I can't figure out how to make Arduino move something (which in my case would be the proper door lock). I thought about a little motor, but I don't know if it is or not  feasible...
To be clear, what I want to do is a simple door lock like this [image]
(or even simpler) being moved from an Arduino program. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is more about robotics than Arduino. I suggest you post it there: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if you need a lock that works w/o power or despite bugs (life safety-level) and with a key, use something like an apartment complex, https://www.amazon.com/Electric-Strike-14C-Extra-Small/dp/B00C0ZENAQ/ref=pd_lpo_60_tr_t_3 , which are pricey, but easy to self-hack. If it's for a hobby or secret compartment, half the fun is engineering something for as close to $0 as possible...

Comment: if you don't need to be able to electronically unlock it, you can use a rubber band, a push pin, a piece of iron/steel, some epoxy and one of [these electro magnets](https://www.amazon.com/Electromagnet-Electric-Lifting-Holding-Solenoid/dp/B01DXF9H16/ref=sr_1_5) to get something working. the rubber band pulls back the bolt, the electromagnet keeps it from being pulled back...

Answer (score 1):

You want a [solenoid](http://www.magnetschultz.co.uk/standard_and_special_solenoids/25/Miniature-solenoids).

Looks like people sell [ones](https://thepihut.com/products/adafruit-lock-style-solenoid-12vdc) which are specifically made for door locks.

Comment: Oh, i didn't even know they exist. But I should install it in my door and it's not so viable. I just need something to put ON my door... By the way, thanks for the answer!

Comment: I've added a link to the generic type of solenoid, as well as the ones made to function as door locks.  That's what you'll have to do - if you want to move something in an in/out direction, a solenoid is what you want. They come in all shapes and sizes - ones to open car door locks, ones to open gas valves. You'll have to dig around and find the right one for your application, but I hope knowing what it's called will get you started.

Comment: Well, sure! I'll search about!

Comment: solenoids are unsafe because strong magnets can reach through the door to unlock by sinking the plunger. make sure it doesn't retract w/o power as well.

Comment: @dandavis That is true. Anyone could get into your bathroom simply by employing an enormous electromagnet in the other side of the door. Those bolts pictured in the question, however, are widely known to be able to withstand a force equivalent to the weight of six blue wales.